# Custom form element name attributes on CForm Yii Framework

Tags: forms, model, yii, gii

I am using CModel (Gii specifically) to generate forms for my Yii application. I have a problem with how it names the `name=""` attributes of my form elements. They look exactly like my table fields on my DB. So, for a table like: `Users`. I get a form element like `<input type="text" name="Users[usr_username]" ... />`

This gives away my table name, and the fields. I understand that I can change the model name to something else to avoid showing my real table name, but I would also like to change `usr_username` to `username` at least. Or even remove the model name on the element's name attribute and have `name="username"` instead.

I would really appreciate your input.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you could use simple text fields like this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::textField('username'); ?>
```

And then map them with your model attributes in the controller:

```
$model->usr_username = $_POST['username'];
```

But you **won't be able** to do massive assignment:

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
```

Comment: it is also worth mentioning explicitly that you won't be able to do massive assignment

Comment: Thanks guys. This helps a lot. I'll figure out a way to make massive assignment work, because I need it too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CActiveForm widget to create the form, which in youre case i think is true because you have generated the model through Gii, you can always set `htmlOptions` property of methods that generate form inputs, like:

```
$form->textField($model,'attribute_name',array('name'=>'your_custom_name'));
```

In above case, the input value will be accessible through $_POST['your_custom_name'], meaning that massive assignment won't work.

Also be aware that if you won't specify the id property of the input it will be the same as the name property ('your_custom_name').

Regards